# Overriding @jsonIgnore in subclass

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class Parent

```
public class Parent
{
   private int id;

   @JsonIgnore
   int getId() {}

   void setId(int id) {}
}
```

I have a subclass which is derived from Parent

```
public class Child extends Parent
{
    @JsonProperty   // just to explicitly tell jackson to serialize this
    @Override
    int getId() {}

    @Override
    void setId(int id) {}
}
```

I actually don't want the id property to be serialized when an object of Parent is returned but it should be serialized when an object of Child class is returned.

I think if Parent was an Interface, overriding the visibility would work, but I am not sure if the behavior is the same with superclass.

Is there a simple solution for this? I would really appreciate your answers. Tx.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What you want in the Child class is not `@JsonProperty` but instead `@JsonIgnore(false)`.